# Get list folder and list file in root folder by dirent.h in C++

Tags: c++

I have a root folder includes

```
+ Test1(folder) > Test2(folder)>Test3(folder)>file1,file2....(file) 
+ Test5(folder) > Test6(folder)>file1,file2....(file)
```

How to get list file with input is root folder in C++. I got list files successfully if list files(file1,file2....) is children root folder(root folder>file1,file2...). But in my case, to get list files I must scan many parent folders. How to get list file in my case? This is my code to get list file if don't have parent folder

```
    DIR *dirStr = NULL; 
    dirStr = opendir(rootpath)
    dirent *nextFile = NULL;
    while ((nextFile = readdir(dirStr))!=NULL)
    {
        // Avoid hidden files
        //Scan all file an dictionary
        if (nextFile->d_name[0] != '.')
        {
                    cout<<nextFile->d_name<<endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Learn from here: [A Recursive Directory-Scanning Program](http://www.johnloomis.org/ece537/notes/Files/Examples/printdir.html)

Comment: On POSIX platforms, `fts(3)` may be an option.

Answer (score 3):

You would use recursion.

Recursive functions are functions that call themselves. There are also mutually recursive functions that call another function, which in turn call the calling function again.

A classy example for recursion is this naive factorial function:

```
int factorial(int x) {
    if (x == 1) return 1; // assume 1
    else if (x > 1) return x*factorial(x-1);
    else throw std::logic_error("factorial called with argument<1");
}
```

Comment: Sorry. In your code, you known the depth parameter. But In my case, I don't know how to parent folder,so i can't know the depth parameter?

Comment: @user2039786 Honestly, "I don't know how to parent folder" either, but you're given an initial folder, and you will need it to build your subfolder full or relative names. Finally, once you do get it almost working, remember that the `dirent *` structure can (and will) be overwritten with each successive invoke in any loop, so prepare to make copies if you intend on keeping those filenames around.

Comment: Thank you. And I have other question that relates with my above above question. I have a function(A function) with input is list files to do something. And I have two folders(same in the above question). And I want to call A function with list files. And the out put file will return in the same folder with input file. How to do it?

Comment: @user2039786: When you are reading ".", then surely you also read ".." somewhere?

Comment: faculty? It's called factorial.

Comment: @sim642: Why not propose an edit? However, thanks for notifying.